# Redux React - How to update store without and user event?

Tags: reactjs, redux, store

I am practising with React-Redux. I know this question sounds quite simple... But I can't figure out how to solve it. I have a function that will generate an object. I want to pass it to the store, but I don't know how to trigger the action without a user action (click button, for example).

```
const MyComponentA = () => (
    <BuiltInCompoment propA={data} propB={ FunctionA } />
)
function FunctionA(object) {
      ...
      FunctionB(object.property) 
}
```

The function FunctionB will return an object (or maybe JSON file). So how do I pass that object (or json) to the store -so as to use it in another component?

Below I show my last attempt. I know it's wrong and has not too much sense. But maybe it clarifies a little bit more what I want (passing data to store so as to render it in a different component which is not a child of the container). The "BiultInComponent" can't be modified to include the prop "resultingData". I am  a newbie so it's quite probable I am wrong about some points/assumptions.

```
   class MyContainerA extends Component  {
       render() 
         return (
             <BuiltInCompoment propA={data} propB={ FunctionA } />
        )
    }

   function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
        return bindActionCreators({resultingData: resultingData}, dispatch);
    }

function FunctionA(object) {

      ...
      var dataToPassToStore = FunctionB(object.property);
      return this.props.resultingData(dataToPassToStore) 
}

exports default connect(matchDispatchToProps)(MyContainerA)
```

Any suggestion will be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Bind an action to the component and you can just call your action through the prop.

Comment: components only exist to display data and handle events (clicks, ajax responses, etc). Under what circumstances do you want to pass this object to your store? Page load? Initial state? Pretty much everything is some kind of "event"

Comment: Thanks for your answers @Win. I have just added a kind of example of what I have.

Comment: @azium Thank u too. Well, hope the example sheds light on what I have & want.

Comment: What's the issue you're having now after your latest update?

Comment: Hi guys! Sorry for my late reply. I solved it. It was as simple as:   `store.dispatch(myAction(dataToPassToStore));`

Answer (score 0):

Look into investigating dispatching [actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html) and [reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html). I believe both of these, which are core to redux, will help you achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi @Patrick. Thanks for your comment. I already have a reducer and an action. What I can't figure out is how to pass it to the store. Should I create a container MyContainerA instead of MyComponentA? It will probably be a truly simple thing... but I can's see it. I read about dispatch and bindActionCreator...

Comment: Is `MyComponentA` connected to the store?

Comment: Hi @Patrick. No, it isn't. It would help if it would be connected? Let's say <BuiltInComponent /> is a kind of form that grabs and processes data using FunctionB. And I want to render that processed data in other part of the app. That's why I need to pass it to the store.

Comment: If you connect a component to the store you can then use `mapDispatchToProps` which will allow you to pass actions as props to the child components. Does that make sense? You should read this also: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Comment: Hi Patrick. I have used mapDispatchtoProps before. I did it with onClick. But in that case, the user triggered the action. What I don't know well is how to do it without any user's interaction.

Comment: Yes so use `mapDispatchToProps` and then with the action you can call it as part of the lifecycle. E.g. `componentWillMount`

Comment: Ooh. I haven't considered that option... Actually, I don't understand well that lifecycle. But I'll research more on that. Thanks Patrick. Hope I can tell you later I got it.

Comment: I'm sure you will!

Comment: @patrick you can also connect with no args `connect()(Component)` which passes `dispatch`